# How I can store a value retrieved from an API and use it throughout the application

Tags: javascript, angular, api

I would like to know How I can store a value retrieved from an API and use it throughout the application angular when i connected.

```
 verifieruserConnect(){
      let headers=new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.jwt});
      return this.http.get(this.BaseUrl+'/verfieruserConnection',{headers:headers}).subscribe(data=>{

        this.userConnected=data;
      });
    }
```

I would like to use this.userConnected in the entire application

Thank you for your help

Comment: you can use localstorage to store it.

Comment: You can also try using redux or some other state manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a service to store this value and use that service to get the value wherever you want.
Something like this.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
  private isUserConneted: boolean = false;

  saveUserStatus(status: boolean) {
      this.isUserConneted = status;
  }

  getUserStatus(): boolean {
    return this.isUserConneted;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes this function is used in the service but the poblem I would like to use this value in auth guard

Comment: ok...may be create diff service to store this value. Inject this new service in the authGaurd and call the getUserStatus function to get the status.